# Error in pom.xml while building a REST web app using archtype jersey-quickstart-webapp Ver 1.19.1

Tags: java, xml, rest, maven, jersey

`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>java.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>RESTFULApp2</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RESTFULApp2 Jersey Webapp</name>
    <build>
        <finalName>RESTFULApp2</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Run the application using "mvn embedded-glassfish:run" -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${glassfish.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goalPrefix>embedded-glassfish</goalPrefix>
                    <app>C:/Users/PATHAK/workspace/target/${project.build.finalName}.war</app>
                    <autoDelete>true</autoDelete>
                    <port>8080</port>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-web</artifactId>
            <version>${glassfish.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>1.20-SNAPSHOT</jersey.version>
        <glassfish.version>3.1.1</glassfish.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>`
[image]

I am unable to deploy a Rest application build with archtype jersey-quickstart-webapp Ver 1.19.1 on glassfish 4. The dialogue box pops up saying unable to deploy. I think this is because of error in POM.xml.

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your post to include those messages as quoted text? Users find it much easier to read code from text rather than an image.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a SNAPSHOT? The SNAPSHOT won't be available unless you specify the snapshot repository in your pom. Maybe you didn't create the archetype correctly, You said you are trying to use 1.19.1, but what you are showing is 1.20-SNAPSHOT dependencies. Th 1.19.1 archetype should pull in 1.19.1 depdendencies

Comment: @peeskillet can you guide me to create an archtype correctly a short ppt format may be, cause I am really struggling with this! How I proceeded was File->New Maven Project filtered with jersey and selected Jersey-quickstart-webapp ver 1.19.1. On clicking next there is a version field with 0.0.1 Snapshot. I have no idea about Snapshots as well as I am new to develop a REST app. could you please throw some light on what are snapshots are how they are used. Also kindly help me get out of this sticky situation

Comment: @fractalwrench I have copied pom.xml file above hope this can be okay....Thanks!